# Resample a datetimeIndex start day wrong

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Source:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    cols = ['Date', 'Time', 'Load', 'Battery', 'Panel',
           'Wind', 'Temp', 'Humidity', 'Volt']
    data = pd.read_csv('test.csv',delimiter=';',header=0,names=cols,
                        decimal=',',parse_dates[[0,1]],
                        infer_datetime_format=True)
    data.set_index('Date_Time',inplace=True)
```

I have this data frame:

```
In [126]: data.head()                                                                          
Out[126]: 
                     Load  Battery  Panel  Wind   Temp  Humidity  Volt
Date_Time                                                             
2018-07-31 13:07:15  13.3    326.3  353.1  0.98  33.93     21.92  3.89
2018-07-31 13:08:15  14.0    314.4  342.5  0.59  33.88     21.84  3.88
2018-07-31 13:09:16  13.4    309.6  335.5  0.39  33.84     22.14  3.88
2018-07-31 13:10:16  13.8    285.1  313.8  2.55  33.71     23.18  3.88
2018-07-31 13:11:16  13.6    292.9  314.7  2.03  33.62     23.25  3.88
......
```

with other 93000 rows. from 2018-07-31 to 2018-04-10. I'd like to resample by taking the sum of values for each 10minute frame. So I tried:

```
In [127]: data.resample('10min',closed='left',label='left').sum()                              
Out[127]: 
                      Load  Battery  Panel   Wind    Temp  Humidity   Volt
Date_Time                                                                 
2018-01-08 00:00:00  136.9   -140.6   -2.9  19.06  291.27    245.63  39.45
2018-01-08 00:10:00  137.3   -140.7   -3.1  15.14  290.62    244.88  39.42
2018-01-08 00:20:00  137.4   -140.4   -2.3  18.03  288.61    246.44  39.44
2018-01-08 00:30:00  137.5   -140.4   -2.2  12.61  286.97    246.83  39.43
```

That is close to what I expect, but the 'resample' remove all the data from the first day (I suspect maybe because the series do not start at midnight), what is the proper way to do the resampling? There are two issues:

1. The first day is missing in the result, i.e. all data removed and the resampled dataframe starts in the first of august and not on 07/31.
2. It is ok to consider intervals that starts at midnight and are so, perfectly multiple of 10min (so, ok for 00:00, 10:00, 20:00) but then I expect that the first grouping is:

---

```
2018-07-31 13:07:15  13.3    326.3  353.1  0.98  33.93     21.92  3.89
2018-07-31 13:08:15  14.0    314.4  342.5  0.59  33.88     21.84  3.88
2018-07-31 13:09:16  13.4    309.6  335.5  0.39  33.84     22.14  3.88
```

---

and then from 13:10:16, of course in the first day of the dataset and not on the second.
Ok. I solved it using:

```
x = data['2018-07-31'].resample('10min').sum()
y = data.resample('10min',closed='left',label='left').sum()
r = pd.concat([x,y])
```

but I think that this must be a form of bug in resample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For output that starts at exactly 2018-07-31 13:07:15, you need to add in the argument `base`: "the origin of the aggregated intervals": [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

Example code:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2018-07-31 13:07:15', format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

minutes = pd.date_range(start, start + timedelta(10), freq='min')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date_Time': minutes, 'Load': np.random.randint(13, size=len(minutes))})

df.set_index('Date_Time', inplace=True)

df.resample('10min', closed='left', label='left', base=7.25).sum()
```

Result:

```
Date_Time           Load       
2018-07-31 13:07:15 11
2018-07-31 13:17:15 1
2018-07-31 13:27:15 6
```

Comment: Your code work as I expected, I do not really need the base, but my code do not work in the same way. Maybe now I'm thinking that depends on the way I read the data from file and on the type of the index dates. I cannot explain why, in my case the code do not work. So, I edited the question and included all code from the beginning.